# paste a string to many column names using a function in R

Tags: r, function, rename, paste

I would like to rename many variable names using a function. For example, adding 'demo' to each one of the variable names for age, gender, but NOT for zipcode, addresses.

So far, I have:

```
 demo <- function(x)
  {
  data$demo_x <- data$x 
   }
  demo("age")
  demo("gender")
```

I've tried paste0 function and some suggestions below. However, I only want to change some of the variables - not all the variables in my dataset.

Comment: `setNames(x, paste0("demo_", names(x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data |>
  rename_with(\(x) paste0("demo", x))
```

A benefit of using `dplyr` is `rename_with` allows you to use [tidyselect syntax](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/) to only apply these name changes to a subset of columns (e.g. `rename_with(\(x) paste0("demo", x), where(is.numeric))` to only rename numeric columns).

In base R:

```r
names(data) <- paste0("demo", names(data))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to change only selected variables? using names(data) would change ALL variable names.

Comment: Yes in both base R and dplyr you can do that, but you need to add more detail to your question. I have already addressed how to to this using `dplyr`. For base R it depends on which columns you are trying to change.